# REACT ROUTER ESCUCHADOR DE CAMBIO DE RUTA

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Espero saberme explicar.

Tengo un componente que tiene que coincidir con las siguiente ruta `<Route path="/page/:page" ... />`.

Dentro del componente tengo una petición a una Api de películas, mediante una etiqueta `< Link >` voy cambiando de pagina tanto en la petición de la Api como en el navegador.

Hasta acá todo funciona como tiene que funcionar, pero cuando vuelvo hacia atrás desde el navegador, el componente no se actualiza.

En el navegador cambia la ruta **localhost:3000/page/5**, **...page/4**, **...page/3**, etc. Pero la petición a la API no sucede.

La solución que encontré es utilizar una etiqueta `< a >` pero eso renderiza toda la aplicación.

¿Hay una especie de escuchador de cambio de ruta en REACT ROUTER para volver a hacer la petición o como soluciono este problema?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
const Movies = () => {
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [pagina, setPagina] = useState(1);
let { page } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    page!==undefined?json(page):json();
}, [])

const json = async (numero=pagina) => {
    let peticion1 = await fetch(`${API_MOVIE}&page=${numero}`);
    let resultado = await peticion1.json();
    setMovies(resultado.results)
}

const handlePage=(page)=>{
    if(page!==undefined){
        json(parseInt(page)+1);
        setPagina(parseInt(page)+1);
    }else{
        json(pagina+1)
        setPagina(pagina+1)
    }
}

return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {
            movies.map((movies, indice) =>
                <div key={indice} >
                    <img src={`${IMAGE}${movies.poster_path}`} style={{ width: "80px", height: "auto" }} />
                </div>
            )
        }
        <Link to={`/page/${page === undefined ? 2 : parseInt(page) + 1}`} onClick={() => handlePage(page)}>siguiente</Link>
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Si pones un useEffect siempre va entrar ahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes escuchar la variable que cambia en params, en este caso debes escuchar la variable page

```
const Movies = () => {
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [pagina, setPagina] = useState(1);
let { page } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
   hago una peticion cada que cambie la variable page
}, [page])
```

Comment: Que grande, me estaba rompiendo la cabeza y era re simple, cosas de autodidacta, jajaja. Muchas gracias, Cristian!!

Comment: es un placer Brian